# Adding a HeaderView to CollectionView when using custom FlowLayout (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've implemented a custom `FlowLayout` subclass, which apparently has precluded me from adding a `headerView` via the `storyboard` (the check box is gone).  Is there any other way to do so using `storyboards`?

There are some answers about how to add a `headerView` programmatically but they're in `objective-C`, how can I add one using `Swift`?

The below doesn't produce a header view and I can't figure out why?

```
 CollectionViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            // Setup Header
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(PinHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)

}
     override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
                //1
                switch kind {
                    //2
                case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
                    //3
                    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind,withReuseIdentifier: "PinHeaderView",
                        forIndexPath: indexPath)
                        as! PinHeaderView
                    headerView.pinHeaderLabel.text = boardName
                    return headerView
                default:
                    //4
                    fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
                }
        }
    }

class PinHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {


    @IBOutlet weak var pinHeaderLabel: UILabel!



}
```

My Layout class:

```
import UIKit
protocol PinterestLayoutDelegate {
    // 1. Method to ask the delegate for the height of the image
    func collectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath , withWidth:CGFloat) -> CGFloat
    // 2. Method to ask the delegate for the height of the annotation text
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat

    func columnsForDevice() -> Int

}

class PinterestLayoutAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

    // 1. Custom attribute
    var photoHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    var headerHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    // 2. Override copyWithZone to conform to NSCopying protocol
    override func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        let copy = super.copyWithZone(zone) as! PinterestLayoutAttributes
        copy.photoHeight = photoHeight
        return copy
    }

    // 3. Override isEqual
    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let attributtes = object as? PinterestLayoutAttributes {
            if( attributtes.photoHeight == photoHeight  ) {
                return super.isEqual(object)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}


class PinterestLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    //1. Pinterest Layout Delegate
    var delegate:PinterestLayoutDelegate!

    //2. Configurable properties
    //moved numberOfColumns
    var cellPadding: CGFloat = 6.0

    //3. Array to keep a cache of attributes.
    private var cache = [PinterestLayoutAttributes]()

    //4. Content height and size
    private var contentHeight:CGFloat  = 0.0
    private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        let insets = collectionView!.contentInset
        return CGRectGetWidth(collectionView!.bounds) - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }

    override class func layoutAttributesClass() -> AnyClass {

        return PinterestLayoutAttributes.self


    }

    override func prepareLayout() {
        // 1. Only calculate once
        //if cache.isEmpty {

            // 2. Pre-Calculates the X Offset for every column and adds an array to increment the currently max Y Offset for each column
            let numberOfColumns = delegate.columnsForDevice()
            let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
            var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
            for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
                xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth )
            }
            var column = 0
            var yOffset = [CGFloat](count: numberOfColumns, repeatedValue: 0)

            // 3. Iterates through the list of items in the first section
            for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0) {

                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)

                // 4. Asks the delegate for the height of the picture and the annotation and calculates the cell frame.
                let width = columnWidth - cellPadding*2
                let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath , withWidth:width)
                let annotationHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView!, heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath: indexPath, withWidth: width)
                let height = cellPadding +  photoHeight + annotationHeight + cellPadding
                let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
                let insetFrame = CGRectInset(frame, cellPadding, cellPadding)

                // 5. Creates an UICollectionViewLayoutItem with the frame and add it to the cache
                let attributes = PinterestLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
                attributes.photoHeight = photoHeight
                attributes.frame = insetFrame
                cache.append(attributes)

                // 6. Updates the collection view content height
                contentHeight = max(contentHeight, CGRectGetMaxY(frame))
                yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

                column = column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) ? 0 : ++column
            }
        //}
    }


    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(elementKind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

       let attributes = PinterestLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: elementKind, withIndexPath: indexPath)
    attributes.headerHeight = 100.0
    attributes.frame = (self.collectionView?.frame)!
    return attributes



    }


    override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
        for attributes  in cache {
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect ) {
                layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the advanced collection view sample code from Apple?

Comment: Thanks, I just checked it out but its in Obj-C =(

Answer (score 4):

You can add header view in storyboard, drag a "Collection Reusable View" and drop it inside the collectionView, then set its `class` and `identifier` in storyboard. Or you can register your custom header class programmatically as shown in your code.

`self.collectionView!.registerClass(PinHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)`

`viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` delegate method is incomplete, case `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter` isn't handled, do the same for footer view as what you did for header view. If you don't see it, set `borderWidth` of header view's layer to a value greater than 0, it might show up.

Comment: Thanks but (1) I can't drag a `reusableView` because Xcode won't let me drop it anywhere in the `CollectionViewController`, and (2) I have  a break point set in `viewFOrSupplementaryElementOfKind` and it's not getting called at all currently.

Comment: @GarySabo, in storyboard, on left most panel, you can see Collection View Controller, under which there is a Collection View, try to drop a Collection Reusable View under it.

Comment: are you using a custom layout though?

Comment: No, I don't, can you add it in storyboard now? Here is a [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j727v4dsdljfn6i/abc.mov?dl=0) showing that.

Comment: I really appreciate you going to the length to post a video!  But I think you'll find that if you set your layout to custom in the attribute inspector you will no longer be able to drag and drop the reusableview

Comment: You can change the layout class after the reusableview is added.

Comment: Good thought but when you change it back to a custom layout, the reusable view that I added disappears :(

Comment: Doesn't happen to me, I use the same code as that in your post.

Comment: @GarySabo Hi, I have the same problem and I don't find the correct answer, did you get it in the end?

Comment: @bey23 unfortunately  no, i wasn't able to figure this one out and moved on...let me know if you do please :)

Comment: Facing same issue but not getting any solution

Answer (score 2):

inside the `prepareForLayout` function add one more `attributes` object for the header. You can append it into the cache at the end like that:

```swift
// Add Attributes for section header
let headerAtrributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
headerAtrributes.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width, height: 50)
cache.append(headerAtrributes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are  you using `PinterestLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)` in method `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind`?

You should use `PinterestLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind elementKind: String,
   withIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`.

You are generating layout attributes for cell instead of suplementary view. As a result your layout attributes don't contain right category type and view kind. That's why even if you register class for suplementary view - collection view doesn't layout its instances.

Comment: Good catch, I've edited in my question, but its still not giving me a header.